# You forgot whether the logic class is at 11 or 12. Your friend knows which but sometimes lies. What should you ask them?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, puzzle

In "Mathematical Logic" by Chiswell and Hodges, there is the following exercise (3.5.3):

You forgot whether the logic class is at 11 or 12. Your friend certainly knows which; but sometimes they tell the truth and at other times they deliberately lie, and you know that they will do one of these but you do not know which. What should you ask them?

There is also the following hint:

Let $p$ be the statement that your friend is telling the truth, and let $q$ be the statement that the lecture is at 11. You want to ask your friend whether a certain formula $\phi$ is true, where $\phi$ is chosen so that they will answer 'Yes' if and only if the lecture is at 11. The truth table of $\phi$ will be that of $q$ if $p$ is true, and that of $(\lnot q)$ if $p$ is false. Find an appropriate $\phi$ which contains both $p$ and $q$.

I think one answer to this problem, in English, is "Would you say 'Yes' if I asked you if class is at 11 today?" but I am having trouble answering this question with a truth table and coming up with a $\phi$ that uses the $p$ and $q$ that the authors specified.

What is a $\phi$ that will work, and is there a systematic way to find it (because right now I am pretty much using trial and error, which feels like the least clever way to do it)?

Comment: There is a **Certain Complication** which I am not sure whether the writers did consider. If we ask something like [If I ask "Does XY=YX ?" what will you tell ?] where there are 2 questions , then there may be a lie to Inner question with a truth to Outer question. There are then 4 Cases. I am not sure whether that was considered or whether it is assumed that both Inner & Outer have same truthiness. That was why I did not give my answer similar to what user Bart has given.

Comment: I’m honestly not sure, so I won’t answer, but here is my input: I think “is it the case that either the answer to this a lie or class is at 11?” If the fiend says “yes” and is lying, then since he is lying, he’s actually telling truth, so he’d be contradicting himself on lying while saying “yes”. So, he can’t say “yes” while lying, which means that if he says “yes,” then he’s telling the truth. Since “yes” is in response to whether he’s lying or class is at 11, and he can’t be lying, then when he says “yes,” class must be at 11.

Comment: @PW_246 It seems to me that asking whether the friend's response is a lie before they have responded would instantiate the liar paradox.

Comment: Hint: the problem seems to become easier if you consider your friend when they tell the truth or lie as two different people. Try solving [this related problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/two-doors-with-two-guards-one-lies-one-tells-the-truth), and see if you can adapt the answer to work here.

Comment: @legionwhale only if the friend lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the hint, we can denote $\phi \equiv f(p, q)$. Since there are just two variables, let's just write down the truth table by enumerating all four possibilities,

| p (truth-telling) | q (class at 11) | Friend's answer to $\phi$ | Ground truth of $\phi$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T | T |
| T | F | F | F |
| F | T | T | F |
| F | F | F | T |

We can double check the ground truth values assigned to $\phi$: it is true in two cases:

1. The class is at 11 (q) and your friend is telling the true (q), or
2. The class is not at 11 ($\lnot$ q) but your fiend is lying, which means the class is indeed at 11.

Therefore, we can conclude that you may just ask your friend $\phi \equiv (p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$, another way is to write it as $\lnot (p\ XOR\ q)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of your friend as a function $f$ that takes boolean values and outputs boolean values, then $f(f(p))$ and $p$ always have the same truth value, regardless of whether the friend is a liar.

"Is $p$ true?" gives you $f(p)$.

"Is your answer to "Is $p$ true?" true?" gives $f(f(p))$.